# Fiddler: show FiddlerScript tab in version 4+

Tags: fiddler

I make extensive use of FiddlerScript.  The version of Fidder (v2.4.5.0) that's installed in my Windows 7 machine has the FidderScript tab showing by defaut:

[image]

However, the version I have instaleld on my Windows 8 machine (v4.4.5.8) doesn't show the FiddlerScript tab:

[image]

Any idea how I can show the FiddlerScript tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install [this](http://fiddler2.com/docs/default-source/telerik-addons/fiddlersyntaxsetup.exe?sfvrsn=2) add-on

**2014-02-23** Updated link here:
http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/add-ons (Syntax-Highlighting Add-Ons)